# Does Nvidia GPUs support pipe like structures?

Tags: gpu, opencl, nvidia, amd-gpu

I am trying to write OpenCL code that takes advantage of the latest OpenCL 2.0 features like pipes. I have been working on AMD GPUs until now and they support pipes. But Nvidia driver doesn't support OpenCL 2.0. So are there any pipe like structures available for Nvidia GPUs? My intention is to transfer data directly between 2 kernels instead of passing it via global memory. So anything that helps me do this can be used.

Comment: Peer-to-peer GPU transfers are exposed in CUDA, but not in OpenCL on NVIDIA GPUs. https://developer.nvidia.com/gpudirect

Comment: GPU direct is for transferring data directly between GPUs right? What i want to do is transfer data between 2 kernels using structures like pipes instead of using global memory buffers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not aware of any. Do contact NVIDIA and let them know you'd like to see OpenCL 2.0 support.